# Grails - db-reverse-engineer:0.5

Tags: grails

I am trying to use "db-reverse-engineer:0.5" plugin with grails 2.4.

I added ":db-reverse-engineer:0.5" to BuildConfig for runtime. Below is relevant entries:

```
    grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
    dependencies {
    runtime ':db-reverse-engineer:0.5'
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'

    }
```

But I get error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad artifact coordinates :db-reverse-engineer:0.5, expected format is <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version>
Error |
    at org.eclipse.aether.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:68)
Error |
    at org.eclipse.aether.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:51)
Error |
```

Comment: It is a plugin and should go to `plugins { }` section.

Comment: Thanks Mahapatro. Sorry for my dumb mistake... first time Grails user.